# jQuery - on click not working for element filtered by dynamic CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have:

```
<a href="http://foo.com" class="SiteClass">
```

Then I via jQuery I do some tests and conditionally update the class depending on the outcome, for example adding `SiteDown` css via jQuery `addClass` method, resulting in:

```
<a href="http://foo.com" class="SiteClass SiteDown">
```

I have the following JavaScript which does not fire:

```
$("a .SiteDown").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('Clicked SiteDown');
});
```

What do I need to be able to fire an alert (or any other code there) when a link with class `SiteDown` is clicked, keeping in mind this class can be added dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You selector is incorrect, remove space to convert it to element with class selector.

```
$("a.SiteDown").on('click', function(e){
  //....
});
```

As of now its descendant selector.

---

As you are approach when manipulation selector, use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using `on()`.

```
$(document).on('click', "a.SiteDown", function(e){
  //....
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the selector problem. This now works fine for an element which already has the SiteDown class when the page is loaded, but does not fire for anything i add `SiteDown` to via `addClass()`

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche So you have to delegate event

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche, Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

In your code `$("a .SiteDown")` you are looking for an element that is child of `a` remove space and it will be ok. use `$("a.SiteDown")` meaning a with class `SiteDown`