# Boostrap - Popover only being fired after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I `addClass`/`removeClass` a CSS class called `SiteClass` dynamically (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180600/jquery-on-click-not-working-for-element-filtered-by-dynamic-css) for background). I bind a bootstrap popover to these like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#SiteList").on('click','a.SiteClass', function(e){
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var strcontent = $(this).html();
    var strTitle = 'Title for ' + strcontent;
    var strMessage = 'Foo <b>Bar</b> Baz';

    $(this).popover({
       html: true,
       title: strTitle,
       content: strMessage 
    });
  });

});
```

The first time I click I get the alert box 'clicked', but no popover. Subsequent clicks and the popover works.

Any clue as to why this is happening and to get the popover to fire from click 1?

Comment: Try adding `$(this).popover("show");` to the end of your onclick function.

Comment: @elethan when I add that line it launches first time but I can't ever close the popover by clicking the link again.

Comment: In that case, try `$(this).popover("toggle");`

Comment: @elethan with this as the last line before closing the .on I get the same problem as the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$().popover(options)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popover-options) simply initializes your popover. You can trigger the display of the popover with:

```
$(this).popover('show');
```

If you would like to toggle the popover on click instead, try:

```
$(this).popover('toggle');
```

I think the reason it works only *after* the first click in your case is that with the first click the popover is initialized with [the default trigger](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) `'click'`, so that subsequent clicks (but not the first click) will trigger it.

Comment: I had to add `trigger: manual,` to my popover options, which works like a charm with your toggle suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of tries finally I have found out this solution and working fine:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", '#add-new', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            $('#add-new').popover({
                placement: 'right',
                html: true,
                container: 'body',
                trigger: 'manual',
                content: function () {
                    return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
                },
            });
            $(this).popover('toggle');
        });
    });
</script>
```